# WooCommerce REST API authentication URL

Tags: php, authentication, woocommerce

I'm working on an invoicing API, and I've been asked to synchronize WooCommerce users' stores with my API. I looked for information in the WooCommerce API documentation and found a request method that authorizes the synchronization of stores with my API. The user has to enter the URL of their store and they will be redirected to the authorization page, but after several attempts I have not been able to get the authorization request to appear.
NOTE:Consumer key and Consumer Secret are properly placed in the code

```
<?php
// Verifica se o formulário foi enviado
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Obtém o URL da loja WooCommerce do formulário
    $store_url = $_POST['store_url'];
    $app_name = 'GESfaturacao';
    $user_id = '1';
    $consumer_key = '[my_consumer_key]';
    $consumer_secret = '[my_consumer_secret]';
    $callback_url = 'https://localhost:8081/server/WooCommerce/callback-autorizacao.php';
    $return_url = 'https://localhost:8081/server/WooCommerce/retorno-autorizacao.php';
    $scope = 'write';
    $endpoint = '/wc-auth/v1/authorize';
 
    // Constrói os parâmetros de autorização
    $params = [
        'app_name' => $app_name,
        'scope' => $scope,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'return_url' => $return_url,
        'callback_url' => $callback_url
    ];
 
 
    $authorization_url = $store_url . $endpoint.'?' . http_build_query($params);
 
    var_dump($store_url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $callback_url, $return_url);
 
    // Constrói a URL de autorização
    // Redireciona o usuário para a URL de autorização
    header("Location: $authorization_url");
    exit;
} else {
    // Se o formulário não foi enviado, redirecione para a página do formulário
    header("Location:gesfaturacao/WooCommerce/index.php");
    exit;
}
 
?>
```

Comment: What does the `$authorization_url` you assembled there look like, and what happens when you visit it?

Comment: According to https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v1.html#auto-generating-api-keys-using-our-application-authentication-endpoint, the WooCommerce authentication endpoint will make a POST request to send the API keys to your callback URL - which means, your callback URL must be publicly available; access to `localhost` won't work from anywhere outside.

Comment: It redirects me to the site I created as a test, but the request doesn't appear. Does the site being hosted locally affect the authorization request?

Comment: _"but the request doesn't appear"_ - instead - errors? "Nothing"?

Comment: _"Does the site being hosted locally affect the authorization request?"_ - the user being redirected back to your return URL will work, because that step happens in the browser; but the POST request to the callback URL likely won't (because that is the remote system making the request, and for that to work, it needs to be able to reach your server.)